# Antonym of expired

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there an antonym of *expired* (in the context of whether e.g. blood products have gone off)?

Comment: Do you mean the date when the blood was taken? or 'not expired'/'still good'?

Answer (score 3):

Colloquially I would tend to use "in date(s)." For example:

> The 2% milk is expired, but the whole milk is still in dates.

There are other antonyms, but they are not exact antonyms and so will only apply to certain domains/subjects:

- valid
- fresh
- good

The last one seems odd, but is in fact quite common:

> Q: Has that milk expired?
>
> A: No, it's still good.

And then of course there is the technically correct answer that I've never heard in common usage:

- unexpired